# Addition of Export-CSV to command in Exchange 365 PowerShell results in junk data while display output is correct

Tags: powershell, exchange

Got one I can't figure out and searching hasn't come up with much.  I am trying to export out a list of all mailboxes with sizes.  Using a Exchange 365 PowerShell I run the following command:

```
Get-Mailbox -resultsize unlimited | get-mailboxstatistics | ft DisplayName,TotalItemSize,Itemcount
```

And the output is as expected:

```
DisplayName       TotalItemSize                  ItemCount
-----------       -------------                  ---------
John Smith        1.217 GB (1,306,765,935 bytes)   5935
Jane Doe          3.39 GB (3,639,886,766 bytes)    9505
Bob Johnson       1.663 GB (1,785,801,420 bytes)   5125
```

I then add a Export-CSV to the command like so:

```
Get-Mailbox -resultsize unlimited | get-mailboxstatistics | ft DisplayName,TotalItemSize,Itemcount | Export-CSV -Path "C:\Temp\365MailboxSizes.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

And the CSV file, other then some incorrect headers, repeats the same identifier the same number of mailboxes I have without any other information:

```
29c8af9bedd244b2f6b4002fa4af87e
29c8af9bedd244b2f6b4002fa4af87e
29c8af9bedd244b2f6b4002fa4af87e
```

What would cause the output of the command to not be the same as the Export-CSV?  I can copy and paste off the output but the same command works fine on-prem.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe not use a format table operator? `New-Object PSObject` is a better fit there.

Comment: That was it.  I'd say its weird that On Prem has no issues with this but there are so many little quirks with Exchange 365 that this isn't surprising.   I changed my Format List over to a Select and the CSV file looks perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[greg-askew](https://serverfault.com/users/20701/greg-askew) got me pointed in the right direction.  The Format List seemed to be messing things up.  Switching to a Select got me the correct output:

```
Get-Mailbox -resultsize unlimited | get-mailboxstatistics | Select DisplayName,TotalItemSize,Itemcount | Export-CSV -Path "C:\Temp\365MailboxSizes.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: as you learned ... NEVER use the `Format-*` cmdlets for anything other than FINAL output to the screen or a plain text item [like a file]. take a look at the error you get with >>> `(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $env:TEMP -File | Format-Table)[2]` <<<. note the `The object of type Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData"`  mentioned there. [*grin*]